# Dynamic Date using Analysis Services in Report builder

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, reportbuilder3.0

Looking for help on this one. I'm working on a report in Report Builder that uses data from the Analysis Services cube and it is giving me a lot of problems when it come to any date/time data. I am trying to build a dynamic report that will allow the report to update depending on when it is viewed. I do this by setting parameters (`@FromDateDate` and `@ToDateDate`). Unfortunately MDX seems to hate dates which makes no sense to me.

My goal is to get data over a span of three months with the `@ToDateDate` being `Today()` and the `@FromDateDate` being 3 months in the past which I am able to achieve with this function `(=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-90,Today()) )`. However those don't go well with MDX.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Work Item Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Date].[Year - Month - Date Hierarchy].[Date].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Work Item].[System_State].[System_State].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Work Item].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Severity].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      StrToMember
      (@FromDateDate
       ,CONSTRAINED
      )
    : 
      StrToMember
      (@ToDateDate
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        {
          [Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].&[{6F43CBFD-2E98-4CA7-B428-0B732603517A}]
        } ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Work Item]
    )
  )
)
WHERE 
  (
    [Team Project].[Team Project Hierarchy].&[{6F43CBFD-2E98-4CA7-B428-0B732603517A}]
   ,[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

I was able to figure out how to essentially inject he appropriate format by adjusting my Parameter Values in the Dataset Properties to this -

```
="[Date].[Date].&["+format(Parameters!FromDateDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")+"]"
```

My two parameters have default values of :

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-90,Today())  and =Today()
```

When I run my report I get the following error:

> The restrictions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOMEMBER function were violated.

Now if I remove `CONSTRAINED` from the `STRTOMEMBER` function I get another error. I have also tried removing the entire `STRTOMEMBER` function and just using the parameters which I can get to work in Management Studio but not in Report builder. Please Help! I have attempted so many different ways and still no success. Let me know what additional information is needed.

Another thing -

If I remove the `T` in the date format of the Parameter Value in the Dataset Property to look like this:

```
="[Date].[Year - Month - Date Hierarchy].[Date].&["+format(Parameters!FromDateYearMonthDateHierarchy.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")+"]"
```

I get the below error:

> The '2017-06-08 12:00:00' string cannot be converted to the date type.

Comment: Also for additional info this is the research I did to get me as far as I've gotten: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/10/07/using-dynamic-mdx-in-reporting-services-part-1/

Comment: Fingers crossed I think I have this one solved!!! My "injection" format for the date type was bad - it needed to look like this instead: Format(CDate(Parameters!FromDateYearMonthDateHierarchy.Value),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "T00:00:00]"
I'll continue to test and update if the fix holds.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the solution if anyone is interested. I've seen a ton of forum posts online with no one having a concrete answer so I can see this is a common problem - the workaround at this link is valid and does work:

[Using Dynamic MDX in Reporting Services](http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/10/07/using-dynamic-mdx-in-reporting-services-part-1/)

My issue was the format of my "injected" date. When running the query generated by my `@ToDateDate` and `@FromDateDate` parameters...

> (note: after changes I made my parameters are now
>   `@FromDateYearMonthDateHierarchy` and '@ToDateYearMonthDateHierarcy`
>   which you will notice in my Parameter Value function)

My Parameter Values appeared in the following format:

```
[Date].[Year - Month - Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2010-12-31T00:00:00]
```

In order to fix the issue for me my "injection statement" had to look like this:

```
"[Date].[Year - Month - Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[" & Format(CDate(Parameters!FromDateYearMonthDateHierarchy.Value),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "T00:00:00]"
```

With the actual date formatting of `"yyyy-MM-dd") & "T00:00:00]"` so in the end the hours minutes and second was what was giving me the headache. The injection works perfectly but just need to pay attention to the Formatting of the date and time. I genuinely hope this helps someone!